# how to understand -keepattributes Signature in Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard

I don't understand how to use this `-keepattributes Signature` in Proguard file?
The Proguard Manual tip is "The "Signature" attribute is required to be able to access generic types when compiling in JDK 5.0 and higher."

I use this attritube test and this is code and progurad code?

Souce Code

```

```
package com.example.pc.myapplication.utils;

import android.support.annotation.Keep;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GenericTypeTest {

  public static void test() {
    Student t = beanRepository();

    GenericInterface<Student> genericInterface = new GenericInterface<Student>() {
      @Override public void print(Student o) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
      }
    };
    System.out.println(genericInterface);
    genericInterface.print(t);

    GenericClass<Student> genericClass = new GenericClass<>();
    System.out.println(genericClass);
    genericClass.print(t);

    genericMethod(t);

    genericCollection();
  }

  public static void genericCollection() {
    List<Student> students = listsRepository();
    if (students != null && students.size() > 0) {
      for (Student item : students) {
        System.out.println(item);
      }
    }

    HashMap<Integer, Student> hashMap = mapsRepository();
    if (hashMap != null && hashMap.size() > 0) {
      for (Map.Entry<Integer, Student> item : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = item.getKey();
        Student value = item.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + ";" + value);
      }
    }
  }

  public interface GenericInterface<T> {
    void print(T t);
  }

  public static class GenericClass<T> {
    public void print(T t) {
      System.out.println(t);
    }
  }

  public static <T> void genericMethod(T t) {
    System.out.println(t);
  }

  public static Student beanRepository() {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("Hello");
    student.setAge(30);
    student.setSex(false);
    return student;
  }

  public static List<Student> listsRepository() {
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      Student student = new Student();
      student.setName("Index" + i);
      student.setAge(i + 30);
      student.setSex(false);
      students.add(student);
    }
    return students;
  }

  public static HashMap<Integer, Student> mapsRepository() {
    HashMap<Integer, Student> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      Student student = new Student();
      student.setName("Index" + i);
      student.setAge(i + 30);
      student.setSex(false);
      hashMap.put(i, student);
    }
    return hashMap;
  }

  @Keep public static class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean sex;

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
      return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean isSex() {
      return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(boolean sex) {
      this.sex = sex;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
      return "Student{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", age=" + age + ", sex=" + sex + '}';
    }
  }
}
```

```

dont add attribetu generated code

```

```
package com.example.pc.myapplication.utils;

import android.support.annotation.Keep;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class GenericTypeTest
{
  public static void a()
  {
    Student localStudent = c();
    Object localObject = new b()
    {
      public void a(GenericTypeTest.Student paramAnonymousStudent)
      {
        System.out.println(paramAnonymousStudent.toString());
      }
    };
    System.out.println(localObject);
    ((b)localObject).a(localStudent);
    localObject = new a();
    System.out.println(localObject);
    ((a)localObject).a(localStudent);
    a(localStudent);
    b();
  }

  public static <T> void a(T paramT)
  {
    System.out.println(paramT);
  }

  public static void b()
  {
    Object localObject1 = d();
    Object localObject2;
    if ((localObject1 != null) && (((List)localObject1).size() > 0))
    {
      localObject1 = ((List)localObject1).iterator();
      while (((Iterator)localObject1).hasNext())
      {
        localObject2 = (Student)((Iterator)localObject1).next();
        System.out.println(localObject2);
      }
    }
    localObject1 = e();
    if ((localObject1 != null) && (((HashMap)localObject1).size() > 0))
    {
      localObject1 = ((HashMap)localObject1).entrySet().iterator();
      while (((Iterator)localObject1).hasNext())
      {
        Object localObject3 = (Map.Entry)((Iterator)localObject1).next();
        localObject2 = (Integer)((Map.Entry)localObject3).getKey();
        localObject3 = (Student)((Map.Entry)localObject3).getValue();
        System.out.println(localObject2 + ";" + localObject3);
      }
    }
  }

  public static Student c()
  {
    Student localStudent = new Student();
    localStudent.setName("Hello");
    localStudent.setAge(30);
    localStudent.setSex(false);
    return localStudent;
  }

  public static List<Student> d()
  {
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50)
    {
      Student localStudent = new Student();
      localStudent.setName("Index" + i);
      localStudent.setAge(i + 30);
      localStudent.setSex(false);
      localArrayList.add(localStudent);
      i += 1;
    }
    return localArrayList;
  }

  public static HashMap<Integer, Student> e()
  {
    HashMap localHashMap = new HashMap();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50)
    {
      Student localStudent = new Student();
      localStudent.setName("Index" + i);
      localStudent.setAge(i + 30);
      localStudent.setSex(false);
      localHashMap.put(Integer.valueOf(i), localStudent);
      i += 1;
    }
    return localHashMap;
  }

  @Keep
  public static class Student
  {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private boolean sex;

    public int getAge()
    {
      return this.age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
      return this.name;
    }

    public boolean isSex()
    {
      return this.sex;
    }

    public void setAge(int paramInt)
    {
      this.age = paramInt;
    }

    public void setName(String paramString)
    {
      this.name = paramString;
    }

    public void setSex(boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      this.sex = paramBoolean;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      return "Student{name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", age=" + this.age + ", sex=" + this.sex + '}';
    }
  }

  public static class a<T>
  {
    public void a(T paramT)
    {
      System.out.println(paramT);
    }
  }

  public static abstract interface b<T>
  {
    public abstract void a(T paramT);
  }
}
```

```

add `-keepattributes Signature` generated code
```

```
package com.example.pc.myapplication.utils;

import android.support.annotation.Keep;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class GenericTypeTest
{
  public static void a()
  {
    Student localStudent = c();
    Object localObject = new b()
    {
      public void a(GenericTypeTest.Student paramAnonymousStudent)
      {
        System.out.println(paramAnonymousStudent.toString());
      }
    };
    System.out.println(localObject);
    ((b)localObject).a(localStudent);
    localObject = new a();
    System.out.println(localObject);
    ((a)localObject).a(localStudent);
    a(localStudent);
    b();
  }

  public static <T> void a(T paramT)
  {
    System.out.println(paramT);
  }

  public static void b()
  {
    Object localObject1 = d();
    Object localObject2;
    if ((localObject1 != null) && (((List)localObject1).size() > 0))
    {
      localObject1 = ((List)localObject1).iterator();
      while (((Iterator)localObject1).hasNext())
      {
        localObject2 = (Student)((Iterator)localObject1).next();
        System.out.println(localObject2);
      }
    }
    localObject1 = e();
    if ((localObject1 != null) && (((HashMap)localObject1).size() > 0))
    {
      localObject1 = ((HashMap)localObject1).entrySet().iterator();
      while (((Iterator)localObject1).hasNext())
      {
        Object localObject3 = (Map.Entry)((Iterator)localObject1).next();
        localObject2 = (Integer)((Map.Entry)localObject3).getKey();
        localObject3 = (Student)((Map.Entry)localObject3).getValue();
        System.out.println(localObject2 + ";" + localObject3);
      }
    }
  }

  public static Student c()
  {
    Student localStudent = new Student();
    localStudent.setName("Hello");
    localStudent.setAge(30);
    localStudent.setSex(false);
    return localStudent;
  }

  public static List<Student> d()
  {
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50)
    {
      Student localStudent = new Student();
      localStudent.setName("Index" + i);
      localStudent.setAge(i + 30);
      localStudent.setSex(false);
      localArrayList.add(localStudent);
      i += 1;
    }
    return localArrayList;
  }

  public static HashMap<Integer, Student> e()
  {
    HashMap localHashMap = new HashMap();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50)
    {
      Student localStudent = new Student();
      localStudent.setName("Index" + i);
      localStudent.setAge(i + 30);
      localStudent.setSex(false);
      localHashMap.put(Integer.valueOf(i), localStudent);
      i += 1;
    }
    return localHashMap;
  }

  @Keep
  public static class Student
  {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private boolean sex;

    public int getAge()
    {
      return this.age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
      return this.name;
    }

    public boolean isSex()
    {
      return this.sex;
    }

    public void setAge(int paramInt)
    {
      this.age = paramInt;
    }

    public void setName(String paramString)
    {
      this.name = paramString;
    }

    public void setSex(boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      this.sex = paramBoolean;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      return "Student{name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", age=" + this.age + ", sex=" + this.sex + '}';
    }
  }

  public static class a<T>
  {
    public void a(T paramT)
    {
      System.out.println(paramT);
    }
  }

  public static abstract interface b<T>
  {
    public abstract void a(T paramT);
  }
}
```

```

Look the code is same, why use this `-keepattributes Signature`.

And this is the whole proguard file:

```
    # Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
    # By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
    # in D:\develop\AndroidSDK/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
    # You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
    # directive in build.gradle.
    #
    # For more details, see
    #   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

```
# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile


-keepattributes Signature

-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-keep class okhttp3.**{*;}
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }

#保留HomeFragment中所有变量的方法不被混淆
-keep class com.example.pc.myapplication.HomeFragment{
 *;
}

#保留utils中未调用方法
-keepclassmembers class com.example.pc.myapplication.utils.FileUtils {
*;
}

#保留support包
-keep class android.support.**{
*;
}
```

```

Comment: You need to add just one line in progaurd.pro file.
-keepattributes Signature

Comment: For more detail you can follow this link.
http://www.optimusinfo.com/android-application-security-proguard/

Comment: yes, I add this to my proguard file. i commit my proguard file add this question. Thank you very much.